# why am I receiving an unexpected EOF while parsing?

Tags: unit-testing, flask, pytest, crud

Below is my code for a simple CRUD test- having followed a tutorial the code should run but keep getting EOF errors. I have redoubled my efforts to make sure the indentation is correct (I think) and checked for :

````
    def test_read_recipe(self):
        response = self.client.get(url_for('read'))
        #self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn(b'mrmanpie',b'hot baked pie',b'200 degress 30 mins', response.data)

    def test_create_recipe(self):
        response = self.client.post(url_for('create'), data=dict(name="created recipe", description="warm recipe", 
        ingredients="recipe1", instructions= "cook for 20 mins"),
        follow_redirects=True
        )
        #self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn('created recipe', str(response.data))
        self.assertIn('warm recipe', str(response.data))
        self.assertIn('recipe1', str(response.data))
        self.assertIn('cook for 20 mins', str(response.data))

    def test_update_recipe(self):
        response = self.client.post(url_for('update', name='mrmanpie'), 
        data=dict(name="updated recipe", description="cold recipe", 
        ingredients="recipe2", instructions= "cook for 30 mins"),
        follow_redirects=True
        )
        #self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn('updated recipe', str(response.data))
        self.assertIn('cold recipe', str(response.data))
        self.assertIn('recipe2', str(response.data))
        self.assertIn('cook for 30 mins', str(response.data))
    
    def test_delete_recipe(self):
        response = self.client.post(url_for('delete'),
        url_for('delete', name='mrmanpie'),
        follow_redirects=True
        )
        #self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertNoIn('mrmanpie', str(response.data)
    #Test each template
    #Test Login
    #Test Logout
    #Test read
    #Test create
    #Test you can update
    #Test you can delete

File "/home/jonasnoori/QA-Final-Recipe/tests/test_app.py", line 89
       #Test you can delete
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing```

would love some help here to see where I am going wrong. Even if I delete my hashed out reminders I keep getting this syntax error.
````

Comment: You've missed to close this line `self.assertNoIn('mrmanpie', str(response.data)`. You need to add `)` and your line should be `self.assertNoIn('mrmanpie', str(response.data))`

Comment: Yes, I have just realised I was missing the closing bracket. Cheers for your attention.